# How to stop playing the first animation and start the second one (Unity)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, animation, animator

I have two animations. Punch animation and kick animation. I set up an Animator to transition between animations. If the first animation is playing, I want to interrupt it and start playing the second animation without waiting for the first one to finish. To enable animations, I use triggers. For example, a character makes a punch, and then immediately kicks. I've tried using boolean variables, but I'm unable to abruptly end the animation and jump to the next one. How to set up an animator?

Comment: remove has exit time and check interruption source.

Comment: @BugFinder I think the interruption source is rather for interrupting the transition itself. The disabling of has exit time should be enough

Comment: possibly but its worth looknig at to see if it makes a difference.. if it doesnt we know better? :)

Comment: Would be better if OP posted more context; Some screenshots of the inspector setup, and the codes on how the interrupt is done. Eitherway, BugFinder's solution is worth a try.

Answer (score 0):

When you define your transition, there is a "Has exit time" setting that you may want to uncheck, or change "Exit time" to 0.

"Transition duration" is another setting that you may want to look into, perhaps.

[image]

To see those options in your Inspector, click on a transition arrow in animator window:

[image]